# Microsoft Sync Framework Filters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

After first synchronization with filters, data created before first synchronization is not downloaded if matched by filter through new association.

I have one SQL Server and several SQL Server CE clients. I create scopes `<MAC>#Setup` where filtered data is sent to the clients in a download DirectionOrder. The first synchronization occurs OK (schema is created and data is downloaded), in the subsequent syncs, data created before first synchronization is not downloaded if matched by filter. Only new inserts or updates are considered.

Answer (score 0):

SyncFx tracks and applies changes per table. assuming you have a linking/association table, when you change the association, it's the association table that is updated. SyncFx will not grab the associated rows from the other tables as it only knows that the linking/association table was updated, not the related tables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it confirms my suspicion. What is be best way to bypass this limitation? I created triggers that update the local_create_peer_timestamp from the associated tables.